# Replace java generic interface in Kotlin for Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm getting to know Kotlin as an Android developer. When making android apps, I'm used to using Databinding, retrolambda, etc. Now I'm a bit lost in how to solve the following case in Kotlin.

### How I would normally do this in java

I have an `Adapter` (extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`) for a `RecyclerView` showing a list of `BluetoothDevice`s. Normally, all my projects have a generic interface TypedClickListener, which will give back the T object of the listitem the user clicked on. Like so:

*The generic interface:*

```
public interface TypedClickListener<T> {
    void onClick(T t);
}
```

*Constructor of PairedDeviceAdapter*

```
public PairedDeviceAdapter(Context context, BluetoothDevice[] devices, TypedClickHandler<BluetoothDevice> handler){
    mContext = context;
    mDevices = devices
    mClickHandler = handler;
}
```

*The adapter's onBindViewHolder: (the holder contains a databinding layout)*

```
public void onBindViewHolder(DatabindViewHolder holder, Int position) {
    holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.device, mDevices[position]);
    holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.handler, mClickHandler);
}
```

*The layout itself:*

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice"/>
        <import type="com.example.TypedClickHandler"/>
        <variable
            name="device"
            type="BluetoothDevice"/>
        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="TypedClickHandler"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        ... // width, height, etc
        android:onClick="@{v->handler.onClick(device)}">
        ... // Row layout etc
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now, putting everything together:

*Passing the TypedClickListener to the Adapter in the Activity:*

```
mAdapter = PairedDeviceAdapter(this, devices, (bluetoothDevice) -> {
    // The code that is ran when user clicks a device
}
```

### How I'm trying to do this in Kotlin

As said, I'm trying to do this with Kotlin. It seems I can skip the step of having a `TypedClickListener`, since I can use a simple inline function `(BluetoothDevice) -> Unit`.

*The PairedDeviceAdapter looks like this:*

```
class PairedDeviceAdapter(val context: Context, val clickHandler : (BluetoothDevice) -> Unit ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DatabindViewHolder>() {
```

The onBindViewHolder looks kinda the same as the Java version of it. However, I can't figure out how to bind my layout to the clickhandler, since I don't have the type of the clickhandler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice"/>
        <import type="???"/>
        <variable
            name="device"
            type="BluetoothDevice"/>
        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="???"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:onClick="@{v->handler.???(device)}">
        ... // close everything
```

### Question

How can I make this same structure in Kotlin, or is there another (smarter?) solution to binding a adapter-row-click to a lambda function defined in the `Activity` (or `Fragment`).

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a method, for example `onSomeClick()` in your class, and call it like this:  `android:onClick="@{onSomeClick}"`

Comment: I want to link the 'click' with the BleutoothDevice as an argument back to the activity (so not to the adapter). How would you achieve this?

Comment: You can define your activity as a handler

Comment: That is a solution, but I'd rather not have my Activity in the BindingLayout, since it would make it unsuitable for reuse (since I can only use that layout with that Activity).

Comment: These days it is common to use a ViewModel, so the above would be `android:onClick="@{viewModel.onSomeClick}". That ViewModel should be for your Framgment or Activity (or even a specific View or feature), the Fragment/Activity can observe a LiveData from the ViewModel and route value updates to wherever they need to go (in your case to some main Activity it seems).